# The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists

Tags: powershell, sitecore-install-framework

While running the script on powershell (admin) as

```
 `Register-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery -SourceLocation https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2`
```

getting error as

```
PackageManagement\Register-PackageSource : The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:4173 char:17
+ ...     $null = PackageManagement\Register-PackageSource @PSBoundParamete ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Power...erPackageSource:RegisterPackageSource) [Register-Packag
   eSource], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.RegisterPackageSource
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Please follow the steps in the blog https://sitecoresolver.blogspot.in/2017/11/sitecore-xp-90-local-instance-setup.html

Comment: I am having similar issue. I tried running the above command but it did not work for me. Below is the error that I am getting - (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgGvs.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open PowerShell as administrator and set Execution policy by running the below command and accept it by saying “A” (Yes to ALL).

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
[image]

Then run the below your command:

Register-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery -SourceLocation https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2

[image]